# Asymptotics for the first eigenvalue for the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, eigenvalues, laplacian

I am trying to understand the existence of positive solutions for the following equations,
$-\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n} u + \lambda u = f(u)$
where $f$ is some non-linearity, say $f(t)=t^3.$

By considering the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n}$ it is clear that $\lambda \leq \lambda_1.$ I was wondering if there are any asymptotics for the first eigenvalue on the sphere that could help me figure out how large the parameter $\lambda$ can be just based on this trivial bound?

Comment: The first eigenvalue of the Laplace Beltrami on the sphere is 0.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune It is widely common in this context to start at zero and "the first eigenvalue" then means the first nonzero one. Mathscinet finds now not less than 160 articles whose title contains both "first eigenvalue" and "Laplacian".

Comment: @Ycor Well, in any case there is a formula for all eigenvalues: $k(k+n-2), k=0,1, \dots$ for the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: This certainly depends on the spherical harmonic expansion of $f$, no? For not-identically-zero $f$, for "most" values of $\lambda$ there will be a unique solution. The obstacles are the eigenvalues of the homogeneous equation. Above $\lambda=0$ (due to the constant), the next obstacle (as @GiorgioMetafune effectively notes) is at $1\cdot(1+n-2)=n-1$. But if your target $f$ is _orthogonal_ to that space of spherical harmonics, that obstacle will not appear. (It's a sort of Fredholm-alternative situation.) Can you clarify?